# How to compare dates from one table with another table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am facing one problem in sql queries, Here is the solution i tried:

```
CREATE TABLE #EventTable(eStartDate datetime,eEndDate datetime)
insert into #EventTable VALUES('2014-10-21 10:57:48.603','2014-10-22 10:57:48.603')
insert into #EventTable VALUES('2014-10-23 10:57:48.603','2014-10-23 10:57:48.603')
insert into #EventTable VALUES('2014-10-25 10:57:48.603','2014-10-27 10:57:48.603')
insert into #EventTable VALUES('2014-10-28 10:57:48.603','2014-10-30 10:57:48.603')
insert into #EventTable VALUES('2014-10-31 10:57:48.603','2014-11-02 10:57:48.603')
```

Second table

```
CREATE TABLE #NeedDateTable(StartDate datetime,EndDate datetime)
insert into #NeedDateTable VALUES('2014-10-22 10:57:48.603','2014-10-26 10:57:48.603')
insert into #NeedDateTable VALUES('2014-11-23 10:57:48.603','2014-11-23 10:57:48.603')
insert into #NeedDateTable VALUES('2014-11-02 10:57:48.603','2014-11-03 10:57:48.603')

SELECT * from #EventTable
SELECT * from #NeedDateTable
```

I want to return dates from #NeedDateTable which are overlapping with #EventTable. So in my case it should return two dates "**2014-10-22 10:57:48.603** && **2014-10-26 10:57:48.603**" and 
"**2014-11-02 10:57:48.603** && **2014-11-03 10:57:48.603**"

Here is my query

```
SELECT Startdate , EndDate 
FROM #NeedDateTable a,#EventTable b  
WHERE ((a.Startdate <= b.eStartDate and b.eStartDate<= a.EndDate) 
OR (a.Startdate <= b.eEndDate and b.eEndDate <= a.EndDate))
```

It is returning duplicate records for above dates. Could you please help in solving my query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what I see in you output that you want records of NeedDateTable which have StartDate = EventTable's eEndDate. if this is the case then here is the query :

```
select a.* from NeedDateTable a join  EventTable b 
on a.StartDate = b.eEndDate;
```

OR if you want to return records of NeedDateTable where exists a record in EventTable whose estartdate or eenddate lies between startdate and end date of NeedDateTable, then:

```
select * from NeedDateTable a 
where exists 
(
  select 1 from EventTable b 
  where (b.eStartDate between a.StartDate and a.EndDate) or
  (b.eEndDate between a.StartDate and a.EndDate)
);
```

[sample sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5b5ed/4)

Comment: this will not identify all possible overlaps

Comment: it seems you are correct. where clause should be like 'where (a.StartDate between b.eStartDate and b.eEndDate) or
  (a.EndDate between b.eStartDate and b.eEndDate)' as we need to find overlaps in EventTable.

Answer (score 2):

### Query

```
SELECT a.StartDate,a.EndDate
FROM NeedDateTable a
INNER JOIN
EventTable b
ON a.StartDate=b.eStartDate
OR a.StartDate=b.eEndDate
OR a.EndDate=b.eStartDate
OR a.EndDate=b.eEndDate;
```

### [Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6bb04/3)

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this to your test tables:

```
insert into #EventTable VALUES('2015-05-10','2015-05-10')
insert into #EventTable VALUES('2016-05-10','2016-05-13')
insert into #NeedDateTable VALUES('2015-05-10','2015-05-10')
insert into #NeedDateTable VALUES('2016-05-11','2016-05-12')
```

Both examples will overlap, but the other answers will currently fail to identify one of these overlaps.

Here is how to detect overlaps:

```
SELECT * FROM #NeedDateTable a 
WHERE exists 
(
  SELECT null FROM #EventTable b 
  WHERE 
    a.StartDate <= b.eEndDate and
    a.EndDate >= b.eStartDate
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Simple Between statement in your Query

```
SELECT  Startdate,
        EndDate
    FROM    #NeedDateTable a cross join
            #EventTable b
    WHERE   a.Startdate BETWEEN b.eStartdate AND b.eEndDate
            OR a.EndDate BETWEEN b.eStartdate AND b.eEndDate
```